# Why are the favicons on the network account "top" tab so fuzzy?

Tags: bug, design, network-profile, favicon

Favicons used as favicons (i.e. in tab titles, window chrome, etc.) look nice and clear. For example, here is a screenshot of the favicon for Linguistics.SE, as seen in a tab title:

[image: Linguistics favicon]

Here is the same thing scaled up 8x without interpolation:

[image]

On the other hand, on the "top" tab of [my network account page](https://stackexchange.com/users/1668748/senshin), it looks like this (screenshotted):

[image]

And the same thing scaled up 8x without interpolation:

[image]

It looks like the favicons on the network account "top" tab are 32x32 images that are being scaled down to 16x16. Wouldn't it make more sense to just use 16x16 images from the outset?

(This happens on Chrome 35 / Windows 7, with a non-retina display.)

Comment: Or better yet, svg...

Comment: They look fine to me, on my retina screen, OS X 10.9 and Chrome 35. I see full-resolution icons. What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: http://cdn.sstatic.net/japanese/img/favicon.ico is used, so it may be that your *browser* is rendering the 16x16 version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, the downscaling from 32x32 to 16x16 is presumably happening in my browser. The same thing happens on all browsers on my machine, though - this is more to do with my lack of a retina display, I suspect.