# Some beta site favicons are capitalized differently in different places

Tags: bug, design, beta-sites, favicon

If you take a look at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233707/224428), you will see that the favicon for Linguistics.SE sometimes reads "LNG", and at other times reads "Lng". The same is true for at least the following sites:

- Linguistics - "LNG" vs "Lng"
- Japanese - "JP" vs "Jp"
- eBooks - "EB" vs "eB"
- Movies & TV - "MTV" vs "MATV" (not a capitalization issue, but still)

This issue does not exist for at least the following sites:

- Earth Science - "ES" everywhere
- Anime - "画" everywhere
- Music - "M" everywhere